# Ring Homomorphism unit to unit mapping

Tags: abstract-algebra

Fraleigh defines a ring homomorphism $\phi:R \to R'$ as a map $\phi$ such that

$$\phi(x+y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$$

and

$$\phi(xy) = \phi(x) \phi(y).$$

As such, it must follow directly from the definition that $\phi(e) = \phi(e \cdot e) = \phi(e) \phi (e) \implies \phi(e) = e'$ and that unity should map to unity. However, under these conditions $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_3 \to \mathbb{Z}_6$ such that $\phi(1) = 4$ is also a viable ring homomorphism. But $4$ is not unity in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ - could someone please explain this apparent contradiction?

I feel like I'm doing something wrong, because some people explicitly write that $f(1_S) = 1_R$ when defining a ring homomorphism, and then why would they do that if it follows directly from another property?

Comment: Why does $\phi(e)=\phi(e)\phi(e)$ imply that $\phi(e)=e'$? That's not correct and unclear. First of all, what is $e$? For which operation do you want it to be a neutral element? Once you answered that question, can you spot a major difference between the commutative group structure $R,+$ of the ring $R$ and the not-so-group-structure $R,\cdot$?

Comment: The constant map to zero shows where your proof breaks down.

Comment: Also, some people ASSUME by definition that a ring hom between rings with $1$ preserves the $1$.  Some people (like me) don't.

Comment: Thank you! I conflated the properties of a group and ring while rushing to understand this. That makes sense that it doesn't follow.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2363835/589